# React: Pass state to {this.props.children}

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a web application that will be able to display some events. Those events will be displayed in different ways depending on the page.

So, for example, I have a component called EventsNews where I want to display the events using the Carousel package. I have other component called EventsPage where I want to display the events in the form of a list. I want to reuse code, so I was thinking on doing the next.

```
    class **EventsNews** extends Component {
        
            render() {
                return (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <SectionTitleBar>News & Events</SectionTitleBar>
                        <h1 className={classes.Title}>Latest Events</h1>
        
                        **<Events>
                            <EventsCards />
                        </Events>**
                        
                        <SeeMoreButton href="/">See All Events {'>'}</SeeMoreButton>
                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            }
    }
export default EventsNews;
```

Then, my Events component will handle everything related to the state and the HTTP handling (to consume from APIs. This component should then pass the state to {this.props.children}.

```
class **Events** extends Component {

    **state** = {
        events: [
            {id: "1", title: "...", local: "...", date: "...", description: "...", url: "Link1"},
            {id: "2", title: "...", local: "...", date: "...", description: "...", url: "Link2"},
            {id: "3", title: "...", local: "...", date: "...", description: "...", url: "Link3"},
        ]
    }

    // TODO: HTTP Handling...

    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                **{this.props.children(this.state.events)}**
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Events;
```

Then my EventsCards will be one of the different ways of presenting the events and should receive them from props.

```
const **eventsCards** = (props) => (
   
    <Carousel>
        {this.props.events.map( item => (
            <CustomCard title={item.title} subtitle={item.date} body={item.description}/>
        ))}
    </Carousel>
);

export default eventsCards;
```

My problem is that when wrapping EventsCards inside Events in the EventsNews component, I'm not able to pass the state from Events to EventsCards.

I cannot declare EventsCards directly inside the Events component (instead of {this.props.children}), because I also need to have a component called NewsList that will be passed as children of Events inside other page. So basically I want to be able to this.

```
<Events>
     <EventsCards /> //display the events in cards.
</Events>
```

or

```
<Events>
 <EventsList /> //display the events in a list.
</Events>
```

in a way that the Events state will always be passed to it's children props.

I've read a lot about Calling children as a function but I was not able to apply any of this to my situation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`children` prop is not a function, so you cannot invoke it. Instead you have to use following util:

```
return React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children), { events }));
```

Let's go through it now. `Children.only` checks if given value contains only one React element. Next we clone returned element and update its' props to contain `events`. If you want to modify multiple children then you should use `Children.map`.

To learn more about such utility functions see: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren